# How to ignore subversion history log

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I use the visualsvn server to manage my svn server, But I want to somebody can not to view the change log which version id less than 1000, How can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, to my knowledge. Either users have access to that entire directory/files (including the revision history), or they don't.